# Redux-thunk dispatch is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I tried to call an action from my component. But, When I run the call the below action from my component
I got a type error that tells that dispatch is not a function. how to get rid of this error.

action:

```
import { FETCH_ALL, FETCH_CUSTOMER, CREATE_CUSTOMER, DELETE_ALL, DELETE_CUSTOMER, UPDATE_CUSTOMER } from '../actionTypes';
import * as api from '../api/index';

export const getCustomers = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.getCustomers();

        console.log(dispatch);
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_ALL, payload: data});
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

component:

```
function Home() {

    const customers = useSelector((state) => state.customers);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getCustomers);
    },[dispatch]);


    return (
        <div style={{paddingLeft: '50px', paddingRight: '50px'}}>
            <header>
                <h1 style={{textAlign: 'center', color: 'green'}}>Customer Relationship Management</h1>
            </header>
            <button onClick={dispatch(getCustomers)}>Fetch Customers</button>
            <div className="heading"> 
                <h3>Customer Details: </h3>
                <button className="homePageButtons"><Link className="homePageLinks" to="/add-customer">Add Customer</Link></button>
            </div>
            <div className="customerTable">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th className="name">First Name</th>
                            <th className="name">Last Name</th>
                            <th className="email">Email</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {customers.map((customer) => (
                            <tr>
                                <td>customer.id</td>
                                <td>customer.firstName</td>
                                <td>customer.lastName</td>
                                <td>customer.email</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The below error occurs:

```
customer.js:11 TypeError: dispatch is not a function
    at customer.js:9
```

I log the dispatch, it is showing the below object...

```
SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: "onClick", _targetInst: null, type: "click", nativeEvent: MouseEvent, target: button, …}
```

I applied the middleware in the index.js file ad below...

```
const store = createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

Comment: Did you try `store.dispatch(getCustomers);` ?

Comment: @b3hr4d No, it's getCustomers is a thunk action creator so no reason for OP to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In useEffect do `dispatch(getCustomers());` in the click handler do `onClick={()=>dispatch(getCustomers())}`

Comment: Shouldn't the click handler call `getCustomers` too?  `{()=>dispatch(getCustomers())}`?